# R and SAS : different results for clustering analysis

Tags: r, sas, cluster-analysis

I'm doing a cluster analysis with R and SAS and I have results which are really different.

I know that the results are random, so a little difference is normal, but the difference is huge.

I perform a test with the famous CARS dataset from SAS.

With R, I do that :

```
kmeans(CARS[,c(8,10)],5)
```

**Result : (between_SS / total_SS =  93.2 %)**

With SAS, I do that :

```
proc fastclus data=sashelp.cars maxclusters=5 ; var EngineSize 
Horsepower ; run;
```

**Result : Approximate Expected Over-All R-Squared = 0.96079**

The difference is smaller, but there is still a difference.
I perform the test few times, and the results are still the same.

Where does this difference come from ?

Comment: No code, no data. I'm sorry, this question is just not answerable in the current form.

Comment: How do you do the cluster analysis in R? Why do you expect the same result? Do you believe that the same algorithm is used by the R and SAS functions? Are default values the same or have you set parameters explicitly?

Comment: In addition, different implementations of the same algorithm could even produce differences.

Comment: I forget to write which function I used in R, sorry.

I don't change parameters.

The data are here : http://www1.datafilehost.com/d/87b8adc9

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure from the documentation:

- R: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/kmeans.html
- SAS: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_fastclus_sect002.htm

that these they rely on different algorithms. SAS documentation vaguely describes a method of "nearest centroid sorting". I don't know anything about this substantively, but perhaps look into other clustering functions (like `hclust`) or other packages to find something comparable.

Comment: Do you know why SAS use the term "Approximate Expected Over-All R-Squared" instead of R-Squared ?

Because maybe the difference come from this approximation, but I don't how to find the within sum of squares with SAS.

Comment: I'd second the 'try other clustering functions'.  I don't know if you'll ever get the exact same results, though; cluster analysis isn't a precise science.